# Designing a MongoDB database - are many embedded documents OK?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, database

I'm trying to make a MongoDB database for a simple voting system. If I were to draw a schema, then it looks something like this:

```
User {
    name: String
  , email: String
}

Vote {
    message: String
  , voters: [ObjectId(User._id)]
}
```

I have some questions about this design when there are a lot of voters for one vote:

1. Sending the whole voters array to the client's side (not to mention caching it in memory) is very expensive, right? Is there a way to get the Vote in a "shallow" way, so when I need vote.voters, it will make another database request to the array of voters?
2. If a voter has voted already, I want to check that and not count his vote. To do that, is there a query I can run in the array of embedded voters to quickly find this?
3. When showing votes, I'd want to show the number of votes *without* fetching the voters array to the client side. Is there some kind of count query I can run to count the voters length?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would add a bit of redundancy to the schema to avoid some of the potential problems you mention. I assume you want to 1) quickly count the number of votes and 2) make sure a user cannot vote twice.

One way to achieve this is to keep both a list of users and a count of votes, and add a clause to the update query that makes sure that a vote is only added if the user's ID is not in the list of voters:

```
var query = {_id: xyz, voters: {$ne: user_id}
var update = {$inc: {votes: 1}, $push: {voters: user_id}}
db.votes.update(query, update, true)
```

(the last parameter is `upsert`, a very nice feature of Mongo)

Then, if you want to show the number of votes you can limit the properties of the result to the `votes` property:

```
db.votes.find({_id: xyz}, {votes: true})
```

You can find a complete description of more or less exactly what you want to do here: http://cookbook.mongodb.org/patterns/votes/

Answer (score 0):

1) You can specify only to return a subset of fields to the client ([docs](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Retrieving+a+Subset+of+Fields)).
e.g. to find a specific message and only return "AnotherField".

```
db.Vote.find({ message : "search for this message" }, { AnotherField : 1 } );
```

2) You could use the $addToSet operator to add a voter into the voters array ([docs](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating)) which (quote):

> Adds value to the array only if its
>   not in the array already

e.g.

```
{ $addToSet : { voters: "Bob"} }
```

3) You could store the count as an extra field in the document and then just return that.

Hope this helps.